# Using polar coordinates to find area of a circle

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Since the area of a polar curve is defined as:

$$
\int_a^b \frac 12 r^2 d\theta
$$

and since $r$ is constant, independent of  $\theta$, can this be re-written as?

$$
\frac 12 r^2 \int_a^b  d\theta
$$

Comment: $r$ is probably not constant though. Unless the curve is a [arc of a] circle then $r$ will depend on $\theta$. To evaluate the integral, you will need to know that function.

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is actually independent of $\theta$, then yes. But then the curve is an arc of a circle centered at the origin, the area you are finding is that of a sector of a circle centered at the origin, and the whole thing is simple and not interesting.

In the general case, $r$ is *not* independent of $\theta$, so your manipulation is not valid. You usually need to do it the long way, substituting the formula for $r$ and finding the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Circle centered at the pole and radius $a$, $r(\theta)=a$. Area is obtained by
$$Area=\dfrac{a^2}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=\pi{a^2}$$

Comment: I think it would be more clearly an Answer if you affirmed that the OP's approach is correct and leads to the familiar area of a circle.  I'm sure you mean to say so with your brief note, but many Readers may jump to your conclusion without seeing an affirmative aspect.